# Is this an undocumented feature of Heroku buildpack API, or a deprecated feature?

Tags: heroku

The Heroku buildpack api documentation [makes no mention](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api) of support for a config_vars property in the YAML hash exported by the *release* script. The only properties documented there are `addons` and `default_process_types`.

However, I have seen [multiple](https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler/blob/master/bin/release) [custom buildpacks](https://github.com/miyagawa/heroku-buildpack-perl/blob/carton/bin/release) making use of such a property.

So my question is, is this some undocumented, working feature? Or is it a feature that has been removed and therefore undocumented?

If it's working, how exactly is it supposed to work? Does it just add the values as environment variables when the slug is running, or does it add them to the configuration you'd see through the management interface?

My guess is that it isn't working because the buildpack I'm using includes a PATH variable that isn't reflected in the PATH I see when I log in to the ad hoc console. However it's possible that I misunderstand how the feature works, or that my release script is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's an undocumented feature which currently works.

Just like the behavior of the addons property provided by the release script, the config_vars property provided by the same script will only be processed the FIRST time the app is deployed.

It creates entries in the config vars which are visible through the management tool, and these will then be available as environment variables in the app.

So if you change the value of config_vars in your custom buildpack, the change will NOT be reflected in any existing apps that have already been deployed using that buildpack. This includes if you change to a different branch of the Git repo where your custom buildpack is stored which has a different release script.